# XML Error: Ill-formed at the Amazon Envelope XML level at (or near) line 8, column 18

Tags: amazon-mws

I am trying to upload product feed on Amazon.de marketplace by using Amazon MWS (in php) but get an error "XML you submitted is ill-formed at the Amazon Envelope XML level at (or near) line 8, column 18". In addition while tried to upload the same feed via scratchpad(https://mws.amazonservices.de/scratchpad/index.html) it gets uploaded.

Here is my XML request:

```
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>M_RUPESH_123456</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
    <PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
        <Product>
        <SKU>p-24862</SKU>
        <Condition>
        <ConditionType>New</ConditionType>
        </Condition>
        <DescriptionData>
            <Title><![CDATA[2012-13 Chile Puma Home Football Shirt]]></Title>
            <Brand>Puma</Brand>
            <Description>description</Description>
            <BulletPoint>football</BulletPoint>
            <Manufacturer>Puma</Manufacturer>
            <SearchTerms>football</SearchTerms>
            <RecommendedBrowseNode>324078011</RecommendedBrowseNode>
            <TSDLanguage>English</TSDLanguage>
        </DescriptionData>
        <ProductData>
            <Sports>
                <ProductType>SportingGoods</ProductType>
                <VariationData>
                    <Parentage><![CDATA[parent]]></Parentage>
                    <VariationTheme>Size</VariationTheme>
                </VariationData>
            </Sports>
        </ProductData>
        </Product>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>2</MessageID>
        <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
        <Product>
        <SKU>p-24862-Sma</SKU>
        <StandardProductID>
            <Type>UPC</Type>
            <Value>4051412990195</Value>
        </StandardProductID>
        <Condition>
        <ConditionType>New</ConditionType>
        </Condition>
        <DescriptionData>
            <Title><![CDATA[2012-13 Chile Puma Home Football Shirt]]></Title>
            <Brand>Puma</Brand>
            <Description>description</Description>
            <BulletPoint>football</BulletPoint>
            <Manufacturer>Puma</Manufacturer>
            <SearchTerms>football</SearchTerms>
            <RecommendedBrowseNode>324078011</RecommendedBrowseNode>
            <TSDLanguage>English</TSDLanguage>
        </DescriptionData>
        <ProductData>
            <Sports>
                <ProductType>SportingGoods</ProductType>
                <VariationData>
                    <Parentage><![CDATA[child]]></Parentage>
                    <VariationTheme>Size</VariationTheme>
                    <Size>Small Adults</Size>
                </VariationData>
            </Sports>
        </ProductData>
        </Product>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

I'm not sure exactly what I am doing wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your XML is not only well-formed, I also successfully validated it against my copy of Amazon's XSDs. Since submitting the same feed through ScratchPad works, I suspect the problem to be elsewhere, and not at all related to the error message you're getting (This is not the first time I've seen Amazon's error messages to be completely off).

Are you using Amazon's sample PHP library or your own code?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about Amazon Scratchpad. Amazon is finnicky so often comparing your xml to the sample in the documentation is your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

try adding following on the first line giving XML version and encoding details

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```